# Android-игра на реальные деньги - разрешено ли?

Tags: google-play, юридические-аспекты

Можно ли (в смысле разрешено ли) сделать и выложить в плей маркет такую игру: игрок вводит реальные деньги на счёт игры (назовём их "монетки"), потом играет на монетки с другими игроками по сети, а потом выводит эти монетки (если выиграл, ну или не всё проиграл) в виде реальных денег (одним из способов)? Способы ввода и вывода денег, например, такие: мобильный телефон, карта Visa, Яндекс.Деньги, Qiwi, WM. Может быть, пополнение монеток будет ещё и обычной Play Market-покупкой в игре (выводить деньги пользователям средствами маркета ведь нельзя?). Игра - никакое не казино или чего ещё, а логическая игра, игроки играют 1х1, побеждает умнейший. Просто на ставки, на реальные деньги (небольшие, начиная от 3 рублей, например). И игрок ни на что не может потратить деньги или никак не может приобрести их в игре, кроме как выиграть у кого-то или проиграть кому-то (ну и ввести/вывести). И сама игра бесплатная, без рекламы.

Надеюсь, что можно, но если нельзя - приведите, пожалуйста, обоснование (или где и как его можно найти), и, если такие есть - способы, как сделать это "легально"

P.S. И что будет, если её выложить на 4PDA, например? Или куда-то ещё, но не в маркет?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно правилам Google Play игры с использованием реальной валюты - [запрещены](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ru/about/developer-content-policy.html)

> Любое приложение, которое предлагает деньги или другие ценности в
>   качестве приза, попадает в категорию азартных.

Согласно законодательству Украины и России тоже.

Comment: Даже если игрок сам их выиграл, и от удачи и рандома тут вообще ничего не зависит, а только от того, как игрок будет играть? Да и браузерные игры есть с реальным выводом денег

Comment: @Aftorik Опишите что ли вашу игру, где случайность вообще не используется. Не то чтобы это имело значение, но любопытно. :)

Comment: @Athari для примера представьте крестики-нолики или точки. Игра 1х1, никаких случайностей, всё зависит только от ума игроков. Ну или шашки, шахматы.     Эх, очень обидно, что нельзя на деньги делать игры. А такая идея была здоровская.

Comment: @Aftorik В крестиках-ноликах победитель определяется тем, кто первый ходит. Кто будет определять первого игрока? Не рандом ли? С шашками и шахматами тоже неоднозначно. Если шахматы полностью не "решены", то некоторые виды шашек решены полностью. Это значит, что при идеальной игре исход предрешён в момент расстановки фигур. Опять же, кто первый ходит?

Comment: Допустим, первый ходит тот, у кого некие очки крутости больше. А если они одинаковые (или оба игрока новички) - то они сначала по-быстрому играют в камень-ножницы-бумагу, и так определяется, кто ходит первый. Так пойдёт? К-н-б - это, конечно, своего рода тоже рандом, но можно и ещё как-то, чтобы было уж точно без рандома.   И я ведь крестики-нолики и шашки привёл как пример, а в моей игре то, кто ходит первым, не определяет победителя и преимущества не даёт

Answer (score 4):

Как уже написали ранее в плей маркете номер не прокатит. Зато существуют альтернативные реальности, например небезызвестный [BlackMart](http://www.blackmart.us/) - там вообще все разрешено :)

Единственная проблема придется как-то писать свою систему монетизации или цепляться к какой-нибудь системе, поскольку BlackMart таковой не имеет.

Ну и я бы еще посоветовал уважать УК РФ и предельно внимательно отнестись к  советам @Athari

Comment: Лучше, думаю, против закона не рисковать. Я уже придумал, как изменить реализацию игры. Но всё равно спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Выше уже писали, что такие игры запрещены. Как вариант только могу предложить такой: 
Найти страну, где это разрешено, опубликовать игру там, написать что специально для этой страны, но типа вот, вы добрый и решили еще и на русский игру перевести. Это будет работать некоторое время, и юридически выйдет чисто, но готовьтесь, что как только игра станет более-менее популярной, в РФ просто закроют доступ к вашим серверам (которые, кстати, тоже должны находиться на территории той страны).

Comment: Хм, а куда отнести фри-ту-плей игры, где вливаются реальные деньги?

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но я уже придумал другой вариант игры :) Конечно, такого азарта, какой был бы при выводе денег, не добиться, но всё же, надеюсь, игрокам понравится моя игра и её реализация

Comment: FreeToPlay - это немного другая ситуация, там нельзя выводить реальные деньги (официальным способом), только платить. Именно это отличие делает их разрешенными. Даже в случае со Steam, где присутствует внутриигровой рынок за рубли, нет возможности снятия денег со счета.